# return a row and avoid null fields inside of it

Tags: php

How to return a row into table form and avoid fields that are null?

```
<?php
$o = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY po_number DESC LIMIT 1");
echo 'The Following Order Information has been submited.';
echo '<table width="70%" border="5" align="center">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($o)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
    } 
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: use `array_filter($row)` before `foreach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `array_filter($row)` before `foreach()`. It removes all empty elements from `array()`.

```
echo 'The Following Order Information has been submited.';
echo '<table width="70%" border="5" align="center">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($o)) {
    $row = array_filter($row); //This line
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($row as $field) {
if(isset($field) && !empty($field)) {
     echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
}
```